# want to send hex data to device via tcp by using php

Tags: php, sockets, tcp

I want to use PHP to connect to a digital meter and get its value (voltage, current, power,...). The command I want to send is `FF FF 00 00 00 04 EE 14 0E 06 00 01 00`

I tried to use `fsockopen` with tcp and use wireshark to capture. It sent options instead of data.

I tried to use `fsockopen` with udp and use wireshark to capture. Transmission control is difference and cannot use hex as data (can use normal text as data).

I already tried to capture from the manufacture's program (win app: I think create by VB6). `fsockopen` with tcp is closest but Transmission Control Protocol is difference
Flags:

- win app: `0x18`
- PHP: `0x02`

after Transmission Control Protocol

- win app: data section with correct hex data
- PHP: no data section but there is another sub section named Options in Transmission Control Protocol

Can anyone please help?

here is my code

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen("tcp://192.168.0.3", 9999, $errno, $errstr);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "ERROR: $errno - $errstr<br />\n";
} else {
  $temp = explode(" ", "FF FF 00 00 00 04 EE 14 0E 06 00 01 00 01 00");
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($temp);$i++)
{
  $obuf[$i] = chr(hexdec($temp[$i]));
  fwrite($fp, chr(hexdec($temp[$i])));
}

   fwrite($fp, $obuf);
   while ( !feof( $fp ) ) { 
      $ret .= fgets( $fp, 4096 ); 
   }
   echo $ret;
   fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: just add. please help

Comment: Cleaned up language, did some formatting.

Comment: Everything in a computer exists as binary/decimal/hex - the interpretation differs. So what is the problem?